# #9073 ImageUpload callback can not be called cross-domain CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9073

I had a unique scenario that requires my image uploader/image management system to be hosted on a separate sever. Because of this, I ran into the security-error-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame error.

Through my research I was not able to identify a clear answer to solving this problem; although there may already be a way to do this/better way, I wanted to post my workaround here in case anyone else can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
console.log('dialof def');
var dialogName = ev.data.name,
dialog = ev.data.definition.dialog;

//verify dialog is of name image
if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {

    //on show create click event listener
    dialog.on('show', function(){
        window.addEventListener("click", evalClickEventType, false);
    })

    //evaluate click event to ensure it is Browse Server button
    function evalClickEventType(event){
        if(event.srcElement.innerText == 'Browse Server'){
            createMessageListener();
        } 

        //if either type of close, or ok, remove clickEventListener
        else if (event.srcElement.innerText == 'OK' || event.srcElement.innerText == 'X' || event.srcElement.innerText == 'Cancel'){
            window.removeEventListener("click", evalClickEventType, false);
        }
    }

    //add event listener for type message
    function createMessageListener()
    {
        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    }

    //set value to txtUrl when event message is emitted.
    function receiveMessage(event){
        CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().setValueOf( 'info', 'txtUrl', event.data );
        window.removeEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    }     
}});
```

then simply replace

```
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( funcNum, fileUrl );
```

with this in your image management solution to pass the url from cross-origin server.

```
var targetWindow = window.opener;
targetWindow.postMessage(imgSrc, "*")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage